# Do these trigonometric identities belong to Antonio Cagnoli?

Tags: mathematicians, biographical-details, reference-request, elementary-algebra

I'm new to this stack community, please bear with me as I try to explain my question properly. Recently I came across with these trigonometric identities (where $ \omega + \phi + \psi = 180^\circ $):

$$\tan \omega + \tan \phi + \tan \psi = \tan \omega \tan \phi \tan \psi$$

and,

$$\sin (2\psi ) + \sin (2 \phi) + \sin (2 \omega) = 4 \sin \omega \sin \phi \sin \psi$$

and a user [who answered the first one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1429470) mentioned that such identity belonged to the 18th century scientist Antonio Cagnoli. I tried to look for sources regarding this but I only could find the [wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonio_Cagnoli) and [this other entry](http://worldcat.org/identities/lccn-n86870249/) in World cat. The OP of the answer had referenced his proof by [this book](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=Lj51QYK1fIcC&printsec=frontcover&output=reader&hl=fr&pg=GBS.PA25) and it is consistent with what it appears on World cat under:

```
Trigonométrie rectiligne et sphérique by Antonio Cagnoli( Book )
18 editions published between 1808 and 2017 in French 
and Undetermined and held by 117 WorldCat member libraries worldwide
```

Although it does mention in the book about the identity with the tangent function it doesn't specifically say about the one with the double angle sine function, which is the one that has triggered my attention the most.

Therefore my question arises that other than this source (the book mentioned) are any others out there which can reassure or tell if these two belong to Cagnoli?.

Initially I wanted to post this question in the Mathstack site but I felt this place would be more proper. I'm looking forward for your answers.

Comment: Many such identities don’t seem especially attributed to Cagnoli... e.g. ([1884](https://books.google.com/books?id=b_g_AQAAIAAJ&pg=RA2-PA79), nº 6, 7) or ([1885](https://books.google.com/books?id=iaAKAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA23), nº 7, 12).

Comment: If you can read German (I can't), you might be able to find what you want in [**Vorlesungen über Geschichte der Trigonometrie**](https://archive.org/details/vorlesungenberg02braugoog) by Anton Braunmühl (1903).

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler Do you mean that he had popularized a method which was well known before him a-la [Tartagia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Reduction_to_a_depressed_cubic), [Simpson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) or [Newton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton-Raphson) and that eventually everyone just named that way because of him?. I don't understand very well what you imply. The documents you referenced aren't accessible from my computer hence I cannot read them, perhaps can you upload a screenshot of the reference what you meant with posting them?.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro It just happens that I studied german long time ago but forgot most of it, therefore I'm just relying on google translate and it looks to be a book about the history of trigonometry. Can you perhaps help me to point a page on where to look exactly?. I'm still in doubt regarding the sines function identity. Maybe is there any other book on english?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't read German at all, but possibly @Francois Ziegler can help, based on [this answer](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7490/help-translate-from-german-a-quote-by-hermann-weyl-in-space-time-matter/7491#7491). I don't have time to look around anytime soon because of some work [= day job] issues, but if I did, I would look through the various books you can find cited in my comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2771222/is-there-a-rigorous-book-on-complete-trigonometry).

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler It is odd why It doesn't show the pages of such books. I can only see the cover of the title but the pages do not show an hyperlink to browse them. The other references (to which I believe you're giving me as a mirror) tell me this message "This item is not available online ( Limited - search only) due to copyright restrictions". That may explain why I cannot read it at google. I didn't know about the point that you mentioned, but it makes sense as in different math books I have there isn't mention of him. But as [someone pointed out him](https://bit.ly/2NVUv3M) I thought yes.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro I'll try to give it a look at the references you mentioned in your other comments. The older books (the french one) which I wrote in my question seem to "refer" the tangent for Cagnoli, anyway I'll try to find if those books can be accessible to me.

Answer (score 4):

Your first identity is indeed attributed to Cagnoli by e.g. Franchini ([1805](https://books.google.com/books?id=m-fmAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA158)), *Encyclopédie du dix-neuvième siècle* ([1847](https://books.google.com/books?id=g4J9_7WX114C&pg=PA377)), or Le Cointe ([1858](https://archive.org/stream/leonssurlathori00coingoog#page/n79), p. 59). It is in the second edition of his *Trigonometria* ([1804](https://www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/15902655), Chap. IV, nº 173) but apparently not in the first  ([1786](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_odSSYA3fokwC)) where Chap. IV ends at nº 128. Woodhouse ([1819](https://archive.org/stream/atreatiseonplan01woodgoog#page/n58)) writes:

> $$\tan.(A+B+C)=\frac{t+t'+t''-tt't''}{1-(tt'+tt''+t't'')}.$$
>   If $A+B+C=\pi$, (which is the case when $A$, $B$, $C$, are the three angles of a triangle), since $\tan.\pi=0$,
>   \begin{align}
> t+t'+t''&-tt't''=0, \text{ or}\\
> t+t'+t''&=tt't'',
> \end{align}
>   which is the theorem given in the [*Phil. Trans.* 1808, p. 122](https://doi.org/10.1098/rstl.1808.0010).
>
> But the theorem has an origin much more remote; for, the above formula for $\tan.(A+B+C)$ and similar formulas for the tangents of $A+B+C+D$, &c. were given as far back as the year 1722, by John Bernoulli, and are inserted in the *Leipsic Acts* for that year, p. 361, and in the second volume of his works, at p. 526 [see [Lemma II](https://www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/1052686)].

Your second identity appears among many similar ones in e.g. Crelle ([1826](https://archive.org/stream/lehrbuchderelem00crelgoog#page/n434)), Grunert ([1836](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_mnZXAAAAcAAJ/page/n635)), Serret ([1850](https://archive.org/stream/traitdetrigonom02serrgoog#page/n82); [1862](https://books.google.com/books?id=7eVlBvMYwYcC&pg=PA45)), Colenso ([1851](https://archive.org/stream/planetrigonomet01colegoog#page/n80)), Müller ([1852](https://books.google.com/books?id=U-DXBTolGrUC&pg=RA1-PA92)), Le Cointe (*loc. cit.*, p. 58), Christensen ([1884](https://books.google.com/books?id=b_g_AQAAIAAJ&pg=RA2-PA79)), *Mathesis* ([1885](https://books.google.com/books?id=iaAKAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA24)), Gelin ([1888](https://books.google.com/books?id=1Qg5iGbPfLsC&pg=PA89), pp. 89, 104-106), etc. None of them attribute it to Cagnoli.