# Original source of these 2 trigonometric identities

Tags: mathematics, trigonometry

I am interested in knowing what is the original source/author of the following identities:

$\tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\tan{\frac{\beta}{2}}+\tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\tan{\frac{\gamma}{2}}+\tan{\frac{\beta}{2}}\tan{\frac{\gamma}{2}}=1\tag{1}.$

$\cot{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\cot{\frac{\beta}{2}}\cot{\frac{\gamma}{2}}=\cot{\frac{\alpha}{2}}+\cot{\frac{\beta}{2}}+\cot{\frac{\gamma}{2}}\tag{2}.$

Where $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are the angles of a triangle.

I ask this question because [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Further_%22conditional%22_identities_for_the_case_%CE%B1_+_%CE%B2_+_%CE%B3_=_180%C2%B0) does not cite sources or mention the original author.

Comment: @njuffa: As you can see [here](https://geometriadominicana.blogspot.com/2020/06/another-proof-for-two-well-known.html?m=1), I am already aware of that proof. My question is who is the author.

Comment: I think this [question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7524/do-these-trigonometric-identities-belong-to-antonio-cagnoli) is somehow related to my question.

Comment: @njuffa: Thank you very much! You have definitely answered my question. At least now I have the sources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After hours of searching through scans of books from the 18<sup>th</sup> and 19<sup>th</sup> centuries in English, German, French, Italian, Spanish, and Latin I managed to find *a* source for each of the two identities.

The first one appeared in a list of trigonometric identities for the oblique triangle in a book by the Belgian mathematician Émile Gelin, *Éléments de Trigonométrie Plane et Sphérique.* Namur: Wesmael-Charlier 1888, [p. 106](https://books.google.com/books?id=1Qg5iGbPfLsC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&dq=trigonometrie&pg=PA106#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> [151] [...] $\mathrm{tg}\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{A} \ \mathrm{tg}\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{B} + \mathrm{tg}\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{B} \ \mathrm{tg}\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{C} + \mathrm{tg}\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{C} \ \mathrm{tg}\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{A} = 1;$

The second one appeared as an exercise in Joseph Alfred Serre, *Traité de Trigonometrié.* Paris: Bachelier 1850, [p. 67](https://archive.org/details/traitdetrigonom02serrgoog/page/n81/mode/2up?view=theater):

> **2.** Démontrer que si $a,b,c$ sont trois arcs dont la somme est égale à $\pi$, on a:
> 1°. $\mathrm{cot}\frac{a}{2} + \mathrm{cot}\frac{b}{2} + \mathrm{cot}\frac{c}{2} = \mathrm{cot}\frac{a}{2} \ \mathrm{cot}\frac{b}{2} \ \mathrm{cot}\frac{c}{2};$

I think it is unlikely that these are the first (original) instances of these two identities in the literature. The inscribed circle of a triangle is already found in Euclid IV. 4. In the first century C.E., Heron of Alexandria already showed that the area of the triangle is $\sqrt{s(s – a)(s – b)(s – c)}$, where the semi-perimeter $s = \frac{a+b+c}{2}$. As far a I know, the ancient Greeks already had the notion of a (co-)tangent, as the length of a shadow cast by a gnomon hit by the sun at a particular angle.

I do not know who first worked out that the radius of the inscribed circle is $r = \sqrt{\frac{(s – a)(s – b)(s – c)}{s}}$ and that $\tan\frac{A}{2}=\frac{r}{s-a}, \tan\frac{B}{2}=\frac{r}{s-b}, \tan\frac{C}{2}=\frac{r}{s-c}$. With modest effort this might lead one to the first formula, for example. I would be very surprised if this did not happen long before the 19<sup>th</sup> century.

Thinking up trigonometric identities for the oblique triangle for use in exercises and exams or as mathematical puzzles for certain journals appears to have been a favorite pastime of 19<sup>th</sup> century mathematicians (or at least this is the impression I got from my lengthy perusal of the literature) and this might be the reason such identities are most readily found in books from that time period.

Comment: If you're up for many more hours of searching (probably it'll be months $\ldots),$ there's the listing of papers in the *Formulae of Plane Trigonometry* sub-section (pp. 463-466) of the *Trigonometry, plane and spherical* section of [**Royal Society of London Catalogue of Scientific Papers 1800-1900. Volume I, Pure Mathematics**](https://archive.org/details/cataloguescie01royaiala/page/462/mode/2up). Also, I recall once coming across a HUGE list of trig identities for triangles published (maybe in 2 or 3 parts) somewhere (early issues of Annals of Math.?) around 1880s to 1900 or so.

Comment: I've got 1850-1921, but apparently I didn't know this in April 2011, according to my reference to his book [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316692623_A_detailed_and_elementary_solution_to_x17_1). It's possible the birth year I later came across -- not sure when, but I was definitely using 1850 [by May 2018](https://www.google.com/search?q=Renfro+%22%C3%89mile+Gelin%22+site:math.stackexchange.com) -- is not correct, and 1851 is correct. However, [this reference](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Belgian+priest+%C3%89mile+Gelin%22) gives 1850. What are your references for 1851?

Comment: (1) Municipality in his place of birth [named a street after him](https://www.faimes.be/loisirs/tourisme/patrimoine/noms-de-rues) and says born 1851. (2) *Revue générale*, Issues 1-5, 1992 [Google snippet](https://books.google.com/books?id=C-bxAAAAMAAJ&q=%22Emile+Gelin%22+1921&dq=%22Emile+Gelin%22+1921&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0yuCLjO_7AhV9NEQIHZMhA-kQ6AF6BAgHEAI) says 1851-1921. (3) This one says 1850-1921 in Appendix 1: Robin Onno Buning, "Henricus Reneri (1593-1639) Descartes’ Quartermaster in Aristotelian Territory." PhD dissertation, University of Utrecht 2013.

Comment: One interesting tidbit about Gelin that I found in a 1916 report on the libraries of German-occupied Belgium is that Abbe Emile Gelin in Huy had a private library of some 5000 volumes, making it one of the largest private libraries in the country. Fritz Milkau, "Das Kriegsschicksal der belgischen Bibliotheken", *Zentralblatt für Bibliothekswesen*, Vol. 33, Nos. 1&2, Jan./Feb. 1916, pp. 1-27 ([scan](https://books.google.com/books?id=QoAEoidReuEC&lpg=PA7&ots=n_4kpziCb6&dq=%22%C3%89mile%20Gelin%22%20%22Huy%22&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%89mile%20Gelin%22%20%22Huy%22&f=false))